# How to store find_by_sql_results in session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my controller code to check login details of a user

```
def validateLogin
  @email = params[:userEmail1]
  @pass = params[:userPassword1]

  if params[:userEmail1] != nil
    valid_user = Userprofile.find_by_sql(["select * from userprofiles where userEmail=? and userPassword=?", @email, @pass])
    if valid_user.count > 0
      session[:email] = @email
      session[:uid] = valid_user.id
      session[:userType] = valid_user.userType # usertype is a column in userprofiles table
      # But here i am not receiving the usertype  it gives error that undefined variable usertype.
      redirect_to "/userhomes/"
    else
      flash[:message] = "Either email or password is incorrect"
      redirect_to '/'
    end
else
  flash[:message]="Fields can not be blank"
  render :action=>'defaults'
end
```

Please help

```
session[:userType] = valid_user.userType
# Error: (usertype is a column in userprofiles table)
```

But here i am not receiving the usertype  it gives error that undefined variable usertype.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this error because you receive an array of objects from `find_by_sql`. You even check the size of the array in your `if` clause.

From your code I think you expect only one returned object. But you still need to get it from the array like so:

```
profiles = Userprofile.find_by_sql(["select * from userprofiles where userEmail=? and userPassword=?", @email, @pass])
if profiles.count > 0
  user_profile = profiles[0]
  #... your other stuff
end
```

Another variant which also much better uses Rails idioms and especially ActiveRecord as is was inteded to be used is to let it construct the SQL by itself which is generally safer, less prone to errors and cacheble.

You didn't write which version of Rails you are using, but for Rails 2.3.x, it looks like this

```
user_profile = Userprofile.first(:conditions => {:userEmail => @email, :userPassword => @pass})
```

For Rails 3.x, it looks like this:

```
user_profile = Userprofile.where(:userEmail => @email, :userPassword => @pass).first
```

Both variants expect that you have a model called `Userprofile`, which you generally require to effectively work with database objects in Rails. What both queries do is to create a new model instance from the first row returned from your query (that's what the `first` does).

Generally, you should get a book or some guide on the internet and learn how to properly use ActivRecord. Note that the API has seriously changed between Rails 2.3 and Rails 3 so make sure to use a guide for your actual Rails version.

And as a final advice, you shouldn't store actual ActiveRecord objects in the session. They would need to be serialized on store and de-serialized on access. What makes it hard (or impossible to track object references.

Also, Rails uses the cookie session store by default, which means that the whole session data is stored in a cookie on the client. The data therein in fully readyabkle to anyone with access to the cookie as it is only signed to restrict tampering with the data, but it is not encrypted. Thus, in your case anyone would be able to ready the (unecrypted) password.

Instead of storing the model object, you should store it's id instead and get the actual (and up-to-date) object from the database instead on each request. This is much easier, saves you from cache inconsistencies (what happens if the user changes her password) and is probably faster than to transfer a huge session cookie from the client on each request.